# How to make People Search Core Results Sortable

Tags: people-search, sorting

I have read several articles showing how to change the sort in XSL. What I would like to have are sortable headers, so that users can choose Ascending/Descending/None.
[image]

Another option I would be willing to look at is simply a drop down box, that allows the user to choose which header to sort by.

Are either of these possible?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: 2010 Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to do this with XSL. I would subclass the core search results web part and change the query results and sort them befor rendering.